# How will the transference number of H+ ion in a dilute solution vary as temperature increases?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

I know that transference number depends on Ionic mobility, which depends on temperature. But is there any equation which describes the relation of Transference number and temperature, any ions like H+.